# What happens to a car when it becomes unregistered in the UK?

Tags: car, vehicle-registration

I am an occasional collector of British sports cars, but I'm moving to Estonia (EU). If I register a car there, and unregister the car in the UK, then later bring it back to the UK, would the car keep it's original date of first registration and all the tax and regulatory rules and prestige that come with owning a 1970s vehicle still apply?